# Rasterize a graphic with Background None gives unexpected result using GradientFilling

Tags: graphics

I would like to combine several images with `ImageCompose` using Images and rasterized graphics.
When I create a `Disk` with `RadialGradientFilling` and want to have no background on the rasterized graphic it gives an for me at least unexpected result.

```
Rasterize[
 Graphics[{{RadialGradientFilling[{0, 1} -> {RGBColor[
       0.7803921568627451, 0.9084967320261438, 1.], RGBColor[
       0.011764705882352941`, 0.5882352941176471, 1.]}], 
    Disk[{3, 5}, 1]}}, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 10}}, 
  ImageSize -> 300], ImageResolution -> 72]
```

gives (without Background->None)

[image]

and using Background -> None

```
Rasterize[
 Graphics[{{RadialGradientFilling[{0, 1} -> {RGBColor[
       0.7803921568627451, 0.9084967320261438, 1.], RGBColor[
       0.011764705882352941`, 0.5882352941176471, 1.]}], 
    Disk[{3, 5}, 1]}}, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 10}}, 
  ImageSize -> 300], Background -> None, ImageResolution -> 72]
```

gives

[image]

Comment: Surprised to find no reaction. Perhaps I missed something obvious but I would still like to know!

Comment: This seems to be a Windows related bug. Could somebody with an apple system and linux try to replicate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a workaround (with the help of Wolfram Support)

```
    Rasterize[
 Style[Graphics[{{RadialGradientFilling[{0, 
        1} -> {RGBColor[0.7803921568627451, 0.9084967320261438, 1.], 
           RGBColor[0.011764705882352941`, 0.5882352941176471, 1.]}], 
          Disk[{3, 5}, 1]}}, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 10}}, 
   ImageSize -> 300], 
  RenderingOptions -> {"3DRenderingEngine" -> "Mesa"}], 
  Background -> None, ImageResolution -> 72]
```